# Strange behavior inside list of figure

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Im pretty in desperate. I updated my MikTeX and out of the blue each entry in my list of figure is like in the picture below.

[image]

I really dont know, which package or what other is interferring. Suddenly is `1.1figure`, before the update it was just `1.1`. If anyone has an idea, I would so happy..

Comment: It might be an issue with MikTeX, but in order to find out, it's better to provide the code that produced this output.

Comment: It's a problem with the previous version of caption package. The last version solves the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is the old version of caption package. The last version solves the problem.

Comment: My answer is not a critique to the author. I think the problem was a little bug what was corrected. It's very easy to probe it, with the two versions of the caption package.

Comment: The release 2015-09-20 V3.3, is ok.

Comment: If the `\caption` package (if used at all) even worked before the update there's no reason to assume that `\caption` is the culprit at all

Comment: there have been two very next updates. The penultimate has the bug.

Comment: Hello, thanks you for your replies. I figured out what was causing the malicious behavior. I used the `subfig` package with the `subfloat` command to align three images horizontally.

Comment: I know that it is barely impossible to guess what the problem is without a MWE. So I was just wondering if anybody else experienced such a behavior or knows something to point me in the right direction. While doing a MWE I acually found the problem, see my comment under my question above.

Comment: As the [`OP's last comment`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269310/strange-behavior-inside-list-of-figure#comment646624_269310) demonstrates, the culprit **was not** the caption package, so your wild guess is not correct and it doesn't provide a valid answer. You should consider deleting it.

Comment: @nerdizzle Instead of adding the answer as a comment, you could add it below as a proper answer. Perhaps add a minimal document to the question illustrating the problem and then, in the answer, show how to avoid it. You can even accept your own answer if you want to.